# Hot to fix 'authentication required' while trying to delete image tag from Azure Registry?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

Ok, I need to delete image with specific tag from Azure Registry(ACR) using Azure CLI and authenticate with service principals.

I have tried already with bash script to first get service principals, then to login to azure with Azure CLI,(and I can see response that I have successfully logged in, with correct subscription id) and then when I try to execute delete command, I'm being asked

```
This operation will delete the manifest 'sha256:531d60fe70137820c7f9e589' and all the following images: 'sampleImage:1.0.0'.
Are you sure you want to continue? (y/n): y
```

and when I hit y, I get : Error: authentication required. Correlation ID: ****

Here is the code :

```
CLIENT_ID = ****
CLIENT_SECRET = ****
TENANT_ID = ****

az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -p $CLIENT_SECRET -t $TENANT_ID

REGISTRY_NAME="acrregistryname"

az acr login --name $REGISTRY_NAME

# Delete image from ACR
az acr repository delete --name $REGISTRY_NAME --image sampleImage:1.0.0
```

What I'm missing here?

expected : delete image successully

actual : Authentication required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, actually, there are three conditions you need to pay attention to.

1. Delete the repository. For this requirement, you just need to have the `AcrDelete` role of the ACR.
2. Delete the image by the tag. For this requirement, you need to have at least two permission of the ACR: `Access Resource Manager`(similar to the Read role) and `AcrDelete`. So the appropriate role with the least permission is the `Contributor` role, more privilege is Owner. But the security role is `Contributor` and it's also recommended.
3. Delete the image by the manifest digest. For this requirement, it's the same situation as the 2.

So, finally, if you want to delete the whole repository, you need the `AcrDelete` role of the ACR. If you want to delete some data of the repository, you need the `Contributor` role of the ACR.

When the role is OK. All steps are below:

```
CLIENT_ID = ****
CLIENT_SECRET = ****
TENANT_ID = ****
REGISTRY_NAME="acrregistryname"

az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -p $CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID
az acr login -n $REGISTRY_NAME
```

You can choose the step below as you need.

```
# delete the whole repository
az acr repository delete -n $REGISTRY_NAME --repository repository_name
# delete the image by the tag
az acr repository delete -n $REGISTRY_NAME --image imageName:tag
# delete the image by manifest digest
az acr repository delete -n $REGISTRY_NAME --image imageName@xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks, it was problem with Role. It didn't have AcrDelete role.
Marking this answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

What permissions does your service principal have?  Note it will need Owner, Contributor or AcrDelete.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles